# How to add meta keywords in news item with contao

Tags: content-management-system, contao

I am extending news module. I have to show meta keywords in news reader module. I have a keyword field in my decay. I have to set the keyword from dca to meta tag. I tried this using

```
$GLOBALS['TL_KEYWORDS'] .= 'keyword1,keyword2';
```

Its working fine. But I need to fetch the value from the record. How can the value can fetch from newslistmodule extended of my extension?

Comment: Are you using Symfony Framework Standard Edition, Symfony CMF, or Symphony CMS(mind use of f's vs ph)?

Comment: I am currently using contao 4.3

Comment: Why Symfony tag then?

Comment: @svgrafov Contao 4 uses the Symfony framework, as well as the basic structure of the symfony/framework-standard-edition.

Comment: @AswathyS you need to be more specific with your question. Where do you want to fetch which values from and why?

Comment: @fritzmg I need to show meta keyword in news reader template. I need to fetch the data in newslistmodule of my extended extension

Comment: @AswathyS so is your question how to fetch your data? What data do you mean? Where is it stored?

Comment: I add an extra field in news dca  .It is stored in tl_news table. Can I fetch this in my module?

Comment: If you use the Contao\NewsModel, it is already available. Without knowing your code, I cannot tell you anymore than that.

Comment: @fritzmg I assign the meta keyword in parseArticles hook.Then my problem is solved.Thank you for your quick response.